# Feeds Importer won't import autocomplete field

Tags: feeds, ajax

I'm trying to use the Feeds Importer plugin. I have a field that's an auto complete and it maps to a NID. I have the NID in the csv file I'm trying to import but it doesn't ever populate that field. It does populate every other field correctly, though.

Any thoughts why this might not be working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the bug... http://drupal.org/node/1426762